# Converting key value pair into a data frame

Tags: r, key-value

I have a key value data in the following format now

```
  column1          column2            column3
  length:30         width:20                          
  length:20          height:10         width:10
```

Now i want to convert this into a data frame in the following format

```
Length                    width        height    
 32                         20       
 40                         30          10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i am looking for a solution that takes treats this as key value pairs and process it into data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the text with `sub`

```
setNames(data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) sub("[a-z]+:", "", x))),
         c("length", "width"))
#   length width
# 1     32    20
# 2     40    30
```

#### Edit

For the updated question,

```
dat <- unlist(dat, use.names = F)              # convert to list
keys <- unique(sub("([a-z]):.*", "\\1", dat))  # extract the keys
keys <- keys[keys!=""]                         # remove empty strings like in your example

## Key-values in list
keyvals <- setNames(lapply(keys, function(x) {
    as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", grep(x, dat, fixed=T, value=T)))
}), keys)

## Convert to data.frame
as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(keyvals, `length<-`, max(lengths(keyvals)))))
#   length width height
# 1     30    20     10
# 2     20    10     NA
```

Comment: Thanks! this will work for the example above but i am looking for a solution that takes key value pair approach and converts it into a data frame

Comment: in "length:30" i would like to consider length as the key and 30 as value . Right now each entry is present in a data frame

Comment: let us add a third component height to the above example 

~      column1          column2            column3
        length:30         width:20                          
        length:20          height:10         width:10  ~

Now considering the above approach will give me the value of height in the second column. My line of thought is if we can use populate the data frame using key values we could avoid the possible mistake in the above scenario. Hope this example helps

Comment: Done. Sorry about that , new to stackoverflow. Have to master those format options

Answer (score 1):

An option using `dplyr/tidyr`.  We convert the 'wide' format to 'long' with `gather`, remove the blank rows (`''`) with `filter`, use `separate` to create two variables ('Val1' and 'Val2') by separating strings at the `:` delimiter, remove the unwanted columns (`select(-Var)`), grouped by one of the variables ('Val1') create a sequence column ('indx'), and convert back from 'long' to 'wide' format (`spread`).

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 gather(df1, Var, Val) %>% 
          filter(Val!='')  %>% 
          separate(Val, c('Val1', 'Val2'), convert=TRUE) %>% 
          select(-Var) %>%
          group_by(Val1) %>% 
          mutate(indx=row_number()) %>%
          spread(Val1, Val2) %>%
          select(-indx) 
 #   height length width
 #1     10     30    20
 #2     NA     20    10
```

---

Or a similar approach using `data.table`.  We `unlist` the initial dataset, and convert it to 'data.table' with a single column (`setDT`).  Using the `tstrsplit` from the devel version of 'data.table' i.e. `v1.9.5`, we split at the `:`.  A sequence column is created ('indx') based on the grouping variable 'V1', removed the 'NA' rows and use `dcast` from `data.table` to convert back from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 DT <- setDT(list(unlist(df1)))[, tstrsplit(V1, ':', type.convert=TRUE)
      ][, ind:=1:.N, V1][!is.na(V1)]
 dcast(DT, ind~V1, value.var='V2')
 #   ind height length width
 #1:   1     10     30    20
 #2:   2     NA     20    10
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column1 = c("length:30", "length:20"), 
column2 = c("width:20", 
"height:10"), column3 = c("", "width:10")), .Names = c("column1", 
"column2", "column3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```